# Azure DevOps Wiki Page not saving

Tags: devops, wiki

I'm having issues with Wiki Pages in our organisations DevOps project.
No one has ever created a wiki page for this project.
When I click on Wiki menu item on the DevOps page sidebar I don not get the "Create Project Wiki" option.
I have the option to enter a Page Title, according to web tutorials this is what you see after you select "Create Project Wiki".
After I enter a page name and click save I receive the following error:
"One or more pages in the hierarchy of the page '/[PageName]' does not exist anymore. Copy your changes if any, refresh the browser to receive the latest pages and try your changes again."

I am a project administrator, so assume I should be able to create a project Wiki. Really not sure what the issue is. Interestingly, I have another project under the same account with same permission level that I can create a wiki page.

I tried searching issues around saving wiki pages, most talked about project permissions which the options reported don't always match what are available (guessing due to age of issue reported in this space) or in the case of project administrator I already have this permission.

Comment: I was able to work around this problem by using the Azure CLI to create a wiki  `az devops wiki create organization=https://dev.azure.com/OrgName/ project=ProjName`

Comment: Please consider adding and accepting your own answer - to close out the question. It continues to appear as a new, unanswered question.

Answer (score 0):

Following on your comment, a more complete answer that worked also for me!

Open Azure CLI, install the azure-devops extension, and then use the wiki create command with the needed parameters.

```
az login
az extension add --name azure-devops
az devops wiki create --project=<project name>
```

More info [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/devops/wiki?view=azure-cli-latest#az-devops-wiki-create).